# Can't make payments with PayPal Android SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing a simple food order app for a friend  with PayPal payment.

To do this, I've watched a YouTube tutorial ( this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae82zSy4CSM&t=78s ) and I've implemented the code in my app. The problem is that if i see the JSON output file, it's all ok but when  I try to pay with my credit card, the money does not arrive on my friend's  paypal account and when i go to check the money on my card, it does not actually decrease. If instead I try to pay with the paypal circuit, it refers to the error "incorrect username / password, please try again" when logging in, even though my credentials are correct.

```
{
     "client": {
     "environment": "sandbox",
     "paypal_sdk_version": "2.16.0",
     "platform": "Android",
     "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },
      "response": {
      "create_time": "2019-09-07T22:05:25Z",
      "id": "PAY-6M507615CG866572Lxxxxxxx",
      "intent": "sale",
      "state": "approved"
     },
      "response_type": "payment"
 }
 {
     "amount": "1.0",
     "currency_code": "EUR",
     "short_description": "Pagamento ordine Itaca Bistrot",
     "intent": "sale"
 }
```

```
public static final String PAYPAL_KEY = "AaJWo...";
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYEMENT = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYEMENT = 2;
public static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
public static PayPalConfiguration config;
PayPalPayment order;

----------------------------

private void configPaypal(){
        config = new PayPalConfiguration()
                .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
                .clientId(PAYPAL_KEY)
                .merchantName("Paypal Login")
                .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
                .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
    }

    private void makePayement(String amount){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        order = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)),"EUR","Pagamento ordine Itaca Bistrot",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent payment = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        payment.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, order);
        payment.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startActivityForResult(payment,REQUEST_CODE_PAYEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYEMENT){

            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

                if (confirmation != null){
                    try{
                        System.out.println(confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        System.out.println(confirmation.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    final AppDB db = Room.databaseBuilder(Carrello.this.getApplicationContext(),AppDB.class,"AppDB").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
                    ProdottoDAO prodottodao = db.getProdottoDAO();
                    //estrapolo da tutti i prodotti la sommatoria del prezzo e il nome dei singoli prodotti ordinati;
                    List<String> nomeProdotti = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < prodottiDB.size(); i++) {
                        nomeProdotti.add(prodottiDB.get(i).nomeDB + " (" + prodottiDB.get(i).getQuantitaDB() + ")");
                    }

                    //riempio l'oggetto di tipo OrdinePassatoDB;
                    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    OrdiniPassatiDB ordinePassato = new OrdiniPassatiDB(00, String.valueOf(currentTime), Double.parseDouble(tot.getText().toString()), "In Preparazione", nomeProdotti);
                    OrdiniPassatiDAO ordinidao = db.getOrdiniPassatiDAO();
                    ordinidao.insertProduct(ordinePassato);
                    Toast.makeText(Carrello.this, "Ordine inviato con successo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //pulisco la lista del carrello;
                    prodottodao.deleteAll();
                    Intent home = new Intent(Carrello.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);

                }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Pagamento cancellato, nessun addebito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if(resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Si è verificato un errore!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYEMENT){

                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    PayPalAuthorization authorization = data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                    if (authorization != null){
                        try{
                            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample",authorization.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                            Log.d("FuturePaymentExample",authorization.getAuthorizationCode());
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the verbose I don't notice any errors attributable to the paypal API. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're working in sandbox. Thats why you can't play with real money on real accounts.

Comment: CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
Yes, because this is my environment config so what should I do?